# Aspera Node URL /ops/transfers?tag=XXXX&view=short_sumary does not return all aspera transfers associated to the tag

Tags: ibm-cloud

The Aspera Node Transfers endpoint:
`/ops/transfers?tag=XXXX&view=short_summary`,
does not return all the aspera transfers associated to the tag.

I do know that it returns a HttpHeader called Link in response where it provides the next URL that contains the iteration_token but even after reaching the end of all, it does not return the aspera transfers.

can anyone help with this ??

Reference Documentation link:
https://developer.ibm.com/apis/catalog/aspera--aspera-node-api/api/API--aspera--node-api#get511225093

Thanks.

Comment: You could improve the tagging and formatting of your questions, maybe provide some more details?